# Golangでは、ランタイムにIndex out of rangeはどのように検知していますか？

Tags: go

例えば、c++で以下のようなコードを書くと、間違ってはいますが、スタックの連続した領域へのアクセスによってランタイムがなにか例外を吐くことはしません。

```cpp
int a[1],b[1];
a[1] = 999; // out of range
std::cout << b[0] << std::endl; // 999
```

また、例えばgoで

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var a [1]int
    var b [1]int
    var i int;

    b[0] = 123;
    fmt.Scan(&i)
    a[i] = 456; // panic
    fmt.Println(b[0])
}
```

のように書くと、ランタイムにindex out of rangeがpanicとして出ます。
これはどのようにして検知したものなのでしょうか？
Arrayはランタイムでもわかるようにサイズを持っていますか？
もしサイズを持っていないなら、どのようにして判定していますか？
もしサイズを持っているなら、なぜerrとして返却するようなものではなく、panicを起こすように作られているのですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://blog.golang.org/slices によると [golang](/questions/tagged/golang) の Array は `len` を持っています (スライスに使えるよう `cap` もあります）。
配列のインデックスが範囲外のときプログラムはクラッシュする（＝強制停止させられる）ともあります。

現代の高級言語においては配列の範囲外アクセスは明らかなバグであり直ちに修正が必要とされています。すなわちデバッガで停止させられるのがほとんどすべてのユーザーに望まれた動きです（なので panic ）。配列外の誤ったデータで処理を続けることができてもうれしくないですよね。

# 現代の高級言語としては範囲外アクセスをチェックしない [c](/questions/tagged/c) のほうが例外的存在